# Web charting libraries for mobile, our own research

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, charts, svg

We are looking for a nice javascript-based library for a web charting application we have been asked to do. The charts will be accessible and should actually be nice to interact with via mobile devices (iOS, Android, and the like). The user will be able to drill-down into some datasets, so the snappier (both processing graphics and loading data) and the more interactive, the better.

Nowadays, there are countless options out there, and many aspects to look at. Based on my research, I have put together the following list. Apologies beforehand for any mistake, it is not intended to be 100% complete or accurate.. but I think that still useful:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0As7T_22rXSbtdF9YeklwcUVXSEdwQnN0a0FvcWpoU2c&output=html

What is your opinion? Do you have any experiences in such kind of application? Maybe some candidate I am missing?

We are narrowing down the choice, but I am still not sure as for what choice is the best bet. Some questions that pop-up in my mind:

- Different ways of rendering the chart (SVG/VML versus HTML 5 canvas). Which one is more suited to browsers in mobile devices? Which one is more suited to user interaction?
- Making it look good. Which libraries allow to easily tweak appearance? Is CSS really powerful for this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "iOS, Android, and the like" - this will have a bearing on the type of usable solutions. If you need to support only iOS and Android then you can reliably use client side javascript type solutions. If you need to support wider range, then you'll be looking at some solution that generates the charts server side and makes them available as an image file.

Comment: +1 for sharing the research BTW...

Answer (score 4):

You missed out [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/charts/)

Answer (score 1):

first of all, if mobile support is a must-have for you, discard SVG as a solution. It's not widespread supported. Canvas in the other hand, is not supported by old versions of IE, but can be simulated via VML with the [exCanvas.js library](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/).

About making it looking good, CSS has nothing to do with these libraries. CSS affects DOM elements, and canvas content is binary data. Canvas is, as the word says, a blank canvas for you to draw in via a Javascript API. Once you draw a line in a canvas element, that information is just pixels in the canvas.

BTW, is a good list the one you collected, and I'm pretty sure it's quite complete. The only intruder in it is Dundas. First of all, is a .Net library, and generates the charts in the server. Second, is deprecated. Dundas is no longer selling components, they're totally engaged with their dashboards solution.

Hope I'd help.

Answer (score 0):

I've chosen [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) for several projects now and it has worked well. It's well documented with lots of examples, configurable, looks great, and is extensible. It is dependent on jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to add [dhtmlxChart](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxChart/index.shtml) to your list.

It's a Canvas based JavaScript charting library that supports different chart types: line, pie, area, bar, radar, etc. dhtmlxChart is distributed under GPL v2 (commercial license is needed to use it in a proprietary project).

(Disclaimer: I work for DHTMLX)

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, but we had to do a similar research recently.

We focused our study on mobile charting libraries (Android and iOS, native or hybrid -with Cordova-) supporting line / area charts. All the information has been gathered from the websites of the respective chart libraries and no personal test has been made (yet).

Here's the result:
https://goo.gl/0tVC6a

I hope it helps.